# Bluetooth won't turn on

Tags: root-access, samsung, bluetooth, 7.0-nougat

I have a GALAXY S6. I have rooted it and have made use of apps such as Greenify, Servicely and Pixel Battery Saver to save battery. The only thing not working is Bluetooth. It is not turning on. I checked Servicely to see if some bluetooth service was blocked but nothing. If I try to share a file through bluetooth it says: "Turning on bluetooth", but after that nothing. I have tried through settings and it does not turn on. At root browser system > app there are: Bluetooth, Bluetooth MidiService and Bluetooth Test. Maybe I have deleted something I shouldn't. Can you help me out? I will not factory reset cause that will delete everything. Thank you!

Comment: Have you installed a custom ROM? You may have probably installed a custom ROM that is currently (at the time of installing ...) at the beta state. Those beta ROMs were unstable and may cause some bugs. However, if you have got your device running a beta custom ROM, then you can always switch back to the stock ROM of your device.